# How to use Symfony TwigComponent from bundle

Tags: symfony, twig, bundle

I am using symfony 5.4.

I have a bundle located in my vendor folder that works fine.

I have created a LiveTwigComponent.

It works perfectly when the template file 'network_list.html.twig' is located in my 'templates/components' folder.
As the logic belongs to my Bundle, i have tried to move it to the 'src/Resources/views/components' folder.
If I do so, I have an error:
"Unable to find template "components/network_list.html.twig"
In my template, I call the component like this

```
{{ component('network_list') }}
```

I have tried to prefix with the bundle namespace as it works for the other templates I have in my bundle

```
{{ component('@MyFooBarBundle\\network_list') }}
```

and

```
{{ component('@MyFooBarBundle\\components\\network_list') }}
```

but doesn't work either, I have another error message

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unknown component "@MyFooBarBundle\components\network_list". The registered components are: network_list").

I suspect I may have to add a config line for twig to tell the bundle to look into my bundle subfolder and i didn't find any documentation about this.

What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The command `bin/console debug:twig` will list all the current twig namespaces.   Typically the `Bundle` suffix is dropped.  So try `@MyFooBar\whatever`.

Comment: thank to the command, I can confirm my namespace appears which was confirmed by the fact I can refer to these bundles templates in my controller. path is correct as well and points to my /src/Resources/views folder of my bundle. But if I try to call the component using the prefix @MyBundleNameWithoutSuffix\\ComponentName, I have an error this component does not exist. same by calling directly the component name without prefix

Comment: So why are you using double backslashes?  Forward slashes are the norm: `'@MyFooBar/components/network_list.html.twig'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the template used to render the component by passing it as the second argument to the AsTwigComponent attribute:

```
- #[AsTwigComponent('network_list')]
+ #[AsTwigComponent('network_list', template: '@MyFooBarBundle/network_list.html.twig')]
  class NetworkListComponent
  {
      // ...
  }
```

Comment: first, sorry for my late reply. I am tried and this is exactly what i was looking for. thanks !

Comment: Glad to see that it helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

The default path is located in `config/packages/twig.yaml`, if you wish to change the default path you can do so here. If you want to add multiple locations, you can do so by adding them to the 'paths' section and defining the file type. The code below should work for your use case:

```yaml
# config/packages/twig.yaml

twig:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
    paths:
        '%kernel.project_dir%/assets/css': css
        '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Resources/views/components': twig
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added the line like you have suggested but didn't change anything. I have tried to call it in my template with the different possibilities i have listed in my first post but the component is not found