# symfony UX Live Component : error 'Parameter "_live_component" for route "ux_live_component" must match "[^/]++ '

Tags: symfony

i am using LiveComponent with symfony for LiveCollection in a form and i have an error

```
Error rendering "MyVeryLongBundleName/components/collection_type_form" component: Parameter "_live_component" for route "ux_live_component" must match "[^/]++" ("MyVeryLongBundleName/components/collection_type_form" given) to generate a corresponding URL.
```

my live component is in a custom bundle MyVeryLongBundleName and the template is stored in 'src/Resources/views/components/collection_type_form.html.twig' in this bundle.

I call my live component like this:

```
{{ component('MyVeryLongBundleName/components/collection_type_form') }}
```

This is how I define my LiveComponent

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace My\Very\Long\BundleName\Twig\Components;

use My\Very\Long\BundleName\Entity\SaasUser;
use My\Very\Long\BundleName\Form\NetworkCoordinatorType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\Attribute\AsLiveComponent;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\Attribute\LiveProp;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\ComponentWithFormTrait;
use Symfony\UX\LiveComponent\DefaultActionTrait;

#[AsLiveComponent('MyVeryLongBundleName/components/collection_type_form')]
class UserCollectionTypeComponent extends AbstractController
{
    use DefaultActionTrait;
    use ComponentWithFormTrait;

    #[LiveProp(fieldName: 'coordinators')]
    public ?array $initialFormData = null;

    protected function instantiateForm(): FormInterface
    {
        dump('called');
        return $this->createForm(NetworkCoordinatorType::class, $this->initialFormData);
    }
}
```

In the profiler, I can see my 'called' message meaning the link between the name of the component used in the view and my component class is correct.

if i debug the live components with this command:

```
php bin/console debug:twig-component
```

I also see my component

I understand from the error that the system doesn't like the slash i use to define the name but i don't see how to do it differently as my component lives in a bundle.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in this thread [How to use Symfony TwigComponent from bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73246434/how-to-use-symfony-twigcomponent-from-bundle), the #AsLiveComponent attribute works the same and you can specify a template path. With this you can shorten the component name and not have the error anymore.